# Is it possible to locally save a Quicktime Movie that is served via (embedded) RTSP protocol?

Tags: android, quicktime, rtsp

I have a Quicktime stream that I would like to save to a local file. (I want to convert it into a sane file format, because the device I want to watch it on doesn't play mov files.)

When looking at the `mov` link for the stream and saving the file in the browser, the `.mov` file is only 1700 bytes large and when looking at it, it does (among binary garbage) contain `rtsp://www.the-server.com/media/filename.mp4` -- which I assume is the data actually streamed by the Quicktime plugin.

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol doesn't exactly raise my hopes of getting at the data, but maybe someone has an idea?

---

Background:

I want to watch [some Uni sessions](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/view/eth:29891) on my [A501 Android tablet](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/model/XE.H6QEN.006) and since there is no quicktime plugin for Android browsers, I somehow want to save the files and copy them over to the device.

Note: The full link can be constructed by combining the JavaScript-showVideo-link URL with the server URL: `http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/`+ <strike>`javascript:showVideo('`</strike>`/eserv.php?pid=eth:29891&dsID=eth-29891-02.mov`<strike>`','800');`</strike>

Comment: can you give an example of a mov link,  so to get the full link from "javascript:showVideo('/eserv.php?pid=eth:29891&dsID=eth-29891-02.mov'"

Comment: or how you got the mov link.

Comment: @barlop: Edited with this full-link info

Comment: +1.  i've just tried it with streamtransport, rtmpdump, riptiger. could be i'm going wrong but seems they're not doing it.  Apparently the issue is it's mdatrtsp:// not rtsp:// and mdatrtsp:// is tricky, The problem, mdatrtsp:// is mentioned here http://stream-recorder.com/forum/download-mdatrtsp-versus-rtsp-mp4-quicktime-qt-t2251.html   You could perhaps try screen capture programs like  WM Recorder suite or Replay Media Catcher but those two are probably not free but not terribly expensive either maybe $40. hopefuilly somebody finds something better.

Comment: @barlop - If I buy Quicktime Pro for 30USD, I should be able to save the movies, or shouldn't I?

Comment: haven't used QT pro, but I just read "QuickTime Pro adds several important features to QuickTime.  The one most people will notice is the ability to save movies from the QuickTime web browser plug-in."   so it might! and if that works it may be  quicker and better quality perhaps too than video capture.

Comment: I have now asked over at the [stream-recorder.com forums](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/showthread.php?p=31400) whether these specific videos can at least be saved with Qicktime PRO.

Comment: perhaps you could ask the guy how VLC can? it probably can't but it means others will realise it's not answered. In addition, the response you got for your thread on that forum doesn't look good, and I assume you worded it well enough, you certainly did here. I suggest trying this one http://forum.videohelp.com/forums/48-Video-Streaming

Comment: @barlop - I haven't gotten around to trying it with VLC yet. I'll post my findings as soon as I have.